# (Ruby,Rails) Multiple simultaneous drag-and-drop items...?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, drag-and-drop

I'm looking for a mechanism in Rails by which to facilitate multiple drag-and-drop items simultaneously.  Basically I want to select multiple and drag.  Obviously I'd prefer to stick with standard HTML items and javascript, but if this isn't possible I'll consider a straightforward Flash implementation.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Scriptaculous doesn't support this, but there are a few extensions floating around out there that might accomplish what you need.  Try [this one](http://simplificator.com/scriptaculous-multidrag/), for example.

Comment: Very nice.  Any idea as to how to get this wired up for wrapper-style use in a Rails app?

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be Rails, it would be Javascript (jquery, mootools and the like) or Flash.

Comment: Understood.  I realize ultimately it's *all* Javascript.  I was simply hoping there were Rails wrappers for Scriptaculous, etc. that would facilitate such functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there are any Rails wrappers for something like this. (99.5% sure.)